# Jquery mousedown mouseup in Chrome/Safari on windows

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have created a page that can scroll with the mouse, like google maps, but when the user does a single click on an object, i want it to show something hidden, i have come up with a very simple solution:

```
var clicking = false;

//mouse clicked down
$(".tile").mousedown(function () {
    clicking = true;
});

//if mousemoves whilst its clicked down dont do mouse up as we are scrolling page
$(".tile").mousemove(function () {
    if (clicking == true) {
        clicking = false;
    }
});

//So if mouse hasnt moved show the hidden object
$(".tile").mouseup(function () { 
    if (clicking == true) {
        //Show the hidden thing
    }
}
```

This works in all browsers apart from chrome and safari on windows? so maybe something to to with webkit? It works if i double click in these browsers but would prefer if its a single click. I was wondering if anyone has come across this problem or knows of a solution? Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mousedown OR mouseup work perfectly in all browsers include chrome and safari on windows

if not work for you, use last jQuery,also try :

```
$(".tile").bind("mousedown",function () { 
    if (clicking == true) {
        //Show the hidden thing
    }
}
```